# me muestra duplicados los registros en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Saben que estoy realizando una consulta para mostrar ciertos registros en un table pero al correr la consulta me muestra 2 veces los registros anexo muestra de los datos que tengo en mi tabla y la muestra de lo que me arroja la consulta

Esto es lo que tengo en mi tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que me muestra la consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui el codigo de mi consulta la cual uso para el reporte

```
SELECT empleados.Nombre,empleados.Puesto,empleados.Departamento,empleados.Turno,tiempoextra.Hora,
asistencia.horaentrada FROM empleados,tiempoextra,asistencia WHERE empleados.codigo_persona=tiempoextra.Id_empleado 
AND asistencia.codigo_persona=empleados.codigo_persona AND tiempoextra.Fecha > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 9.5 HOUR);
```

Este es el reporte para el que utilizo la consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme

Saludos

Anexo codigo de mi base de datos

```
CREATE TABLE `asistencia` (
  `id_asistencia` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `codigo_persona` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `horaentrada` time NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(15) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `asistencia`
--

INSERT INTO `asistencia` (`id_asistencia`, `codigo_persona`, `fecha`, `horaentrada`, `tipo`) VALUES
(1, 253414, '2022-08-19', '08:30:42', 'Entrada'),
(2, 255603, '2022-08-19', '08:36:00', 'Entrada'),
(3, 169679, '2022-08-19', '08:36:07', 'Entrada');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `empleados`
--

CREATE TABLE `empleados` (
  `id_emp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `codigo_persona` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Puesto` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Categoria` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Departamento` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Turno` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `empleados`
--

INSERT INTO `empleados` (`id_emp`, `codigo_persona`, `Nombre`, `Puesto`, `Categoria`, `Departamento`, `Turno`) VALUES
(1, 4048, 'RODRIGUEZ ARREOLA, HUGO CESAR', 'SUPERVISOR DE AREA', 'Administrativo', 'Aduanas', '2do'),
(2, 4817, 'TOY JIMENEZ, ADOLFO', 'SUPERVISOR GENERAL', 'Administrativo', 'Embarques', '1ro'),
(3, 8559, 'MUÑOZ TREVIZO, MIGUEL ANGEL', 'MATERIALISTA', 'Indirecto', 'Kit\'s', '2do'),
(4, 15132, 'RAMIREZ TORRES, ELENA', 'SUPERVISOR DE AREA', 'Administrativo', 'Materiales JMC', '1ro'),
(5, 16955, 'LOPEZ SANCHEZ, NATANAEL', 'SUPERVISOR GENERAL', 'Administrativo', 'Aduanas', '1ro'),
(6, 22066, 'TARIN RAMIREZ, SIMON', 'ASISTENTE DE GERENTE GENERAL', 'Management', 'Materiales JMC', '1ro'),
(7, 23369, 'MELENDEZ AGUIRRE, JOSE ISABEL', 'INGENIERO', 'Administrativo', 'SQA', '1ro'),
(8, 27194, 'ROSALES SILVA, ARACELI', 'SUPERVISOR JUNIOR', 'Indirecto', 'Recibos', '1ro'),
(9, 35943, 'MARTINEZ CHAVARRIA, MARTHA', 'AUDITOR DE CALIDAD', 'Indirecto', 'SQA', '3ro'),
(10, 71324, 'BELTRAN ORTIZ, IBEL JANETH', 'MATERIALISTA', 'Indirecto', 'MATERIALES PROTOTIPOS JMC', '3ro'),

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `tiempoextra`
--

CREATE TABLE `tiempoextra` (
  `IdTE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `Hora` time NOT NULL,
  `Razon` varchar(600) NOT NULL,
  `Id_empleado` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `tiempoextra`
--

INSERT INTO `tiempoextra` (`IdTE`, `Fecha`, `Hora`, `Razon`, `Id_empleado`) VALUES
(1, '2022-08-19', '06:30:00', 'Inventario', 169679),
(2, '2022-08-19', '07:00:00', 'Por cuestiones de inventario', 255603),
(3, '2022-08-19', '08:24:00', 'Inventario', 253414);
```

Comment: Pásanos el dataset (phpmyadmin, export)

Comment: @DavidJP disculpa un poco mi ignorancia lo pongo en codigo de toda la base de datos o como disculpa

Comment: Con que esté la estructura de las tablas, algún dato de muestra y el resultado que esperas para esos datos, ya es suficiente para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: puedes usar esta herramienta para montar un ejemplo demostrable de tu tabla y base de datos: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Ya añadi el codigo de la base de datos

Comment: ¿Usaste `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @padaleiana no lo utilice

Comment: Los datos que nos pasas nos son suficientes para reproducir la situación que te estás encontrando (faltan los empleados implicados y las duplicidades en `asistencia` y `tiempoextra`). Por favor, muéstranos lo que se debería obtener para los datos de muestra que aportes finalmente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías agrupar de esta forma:

```
SELECT
  empleados.codigo_persona,
  empleados.Nombre,
  empleados.Puesto,
  empleados.Departamento,
  empleados.Turno,
  MAX(tiempoextra.Hora) hora_tiempo_extra,
  MIN(IF(tipo='Entrada',asistencia.horaentrada,NULL)) entrada,
  MAX(IF(tipo='Salida',asistencia.horaentrada,NULL)) salida
  FROM empleados,tiempoextra,asistencia
  WHERE empleados.codigo_persona = tiempoextra.Id_empleado
  AND asistencia.codigo_persona = empleados.codigo_persona
  AND tiempoextra.fecha > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 + 9.5 HOUR)
  GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5;
```

Completando los datos que aportas con:

```
INSERT INTO empleados (id_emp, codigo_persona, Nombre, Puesto, Categoria, Departamento, Turno) VALUES
  (169679,169679,'BALDERAS GAYTAN, JOSE JACOBO','GERENTE DE GRUPO','','Materiales JMC','1ro');
INSERT INTO asistencia (id_asistencia, codigo_persona, fecha, horaentrada, tipo) VALUES
  (4,169679,'2022-08-19','04:28:42','Salida');
UPDATE asistencia set horaentrada='04:28:06'
  WHERE id_asistencia=3;
```

Obtendrás:

```
+----------------+------------------------------+------------------+----------------+-------+-------------------+----------+----------+
| codigo_persona | Nombre                       | Puesto           | Departamento   | Turno | hora_tiempo_extra | entrada  | salida   |
+----------------+------------------------------+------------------+----------------+-------+-------------------+----------+----------+
|         169679 | BALDERAS GAYTAN, JOSE JACOBO | GERENTE DE GRUPO | Materiales JMC | 1ro   | 06:30:00          | 04:28:06 | 04:28:42 |
+----------------+------------------------------+------------------+----------------+-------+-------------------+----------+----------+
```

En vez del duplicado:

```
+------------------------------+------------------+----------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| Nombre                       | Puesto           | Departamento   | Turno | Hora     | horaentrada |
+------------------------------+------------------+----------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| BALDERAS GAYTAN, JOSE JACOBO | GERENTE DE GRUPO | Materiales JMC | 1ro   | 06:30:00 | 04:28:06    |
| BALDERAS GAYTAN, JOSE JACOBO | GERENTE DE GRUPO | Materiales JMC | 1ro   | 06:30:00 | 04:28:42    |
+------------------------------+------------------+----------------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

Fíjate en que he añadido 24 horas para que continúes visualizando hoy los registros de ayer.

Al combinar tablas, dado que hay tablas que tienen dos registros para el mismo día (entrada y salida), necesariamente se te duplicarán líneas. Para evitarlo, además de agrupar, se recurre a totales condicionados con el `IF()` que puedes observar.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: No estaría demás explicar qué son los números del 1 al 5 en el `GROUP BY` :)

Comment: Son los 5 primeros campos que aparecen tras el `SELECT`, es el `position` que figura en el manual. Aunque el `id` sea único y ahora mismo sean opcionales, conviene que figuren por si en futuras versiones MySQL se pone más restrictivo

Comment: Buen dia @DavidJP  muchas gracias por la ayuda lo implementare y vere como da el resultado

Comment: @DavidJP muchas gracias me funciono excelente